# How to implement Firebase Cloud messaging with Foreground application?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to receive a message in an Activity with the application in the foreground and display the message with Toast? I receive notification only when the app is in the background.

Something like messages in real time.

Please help me !!

Comment: you should create a service for it

Comment: in my answer just copy and paste the service classes and include in it and it will run in background

Comment: You do know that firebase is a realt-time database, right? So long as your app os connected to the database, every update (depending on your implementation), will be received immediately.

Comment: @intj good idea. But keep in mind that using the Firebase Database would keep an (extra) socket open. If the updates are relatively frequent, that might be worth it. But for other scenarios, using Cloud Messaging's more "ambient" notification mechanism may be preferable.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for mentioning that. I guess it's all up to him. Depending on his use case. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the oncreate method of activity to display toast.write.

```
registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(),new IntentFilter("MyReceiver"));
```

then create a MyReceiver BroadCastReceiver as the inner class in that Activity.
as.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Toast.makeText(context,intent.getStringExtra("from")+"         "+intent.getStringExtra("message"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
    ///finally you have to write the following codes on the 
    onMessageReceived
    Intent intents=new Intent();
    intents.setAction("MyReceiver");
    intents.putExtra("message",message.getData().get("message"));
    intents.putExtra("from",message.getData().get("from"));
    getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(intents);
```

Comment: thank you frank for editting the answer , the code was not well arranged

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Cloud Messaging [Android Quickstart app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) demonstrates registering an Android app for Notifications and handling the receipt of a message. InstanceID allows easy registration while FirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIDService enable token refreshes and message handling on the client.

Comment: But the sample doesn't demonstrates how to handle FCM on activity scope.