# How to Implement Push Notification based on Data in a Databse?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, push-notification, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

So I am trying to implement a push notification using a databse that is hosted on a server . 
There are bunch of users connected to the application and each of them have their own unique ID and Password . 
Now There is one common table which maintains a data of all the users. Only an admin can add the data to this table . Now I want to provide a push notification to the user when the Admin adds the data for a particular ID .

That is , lets say there are two users with IDs 001 and 002. Now the Admin adds an item to the databse "001" ,"xyz" "$20" . So i want to display on the phone of user "001" that a new data has been added under his name and he can go and check it out . 
I am trying to acheive this using GCM and Firebase. 
Can aynone help me out ? Some code or explanation or a good tutorial works fine too . 
Thank You

Comment: You say you're trying it out with GCM and Firebase. Have you tried anything so far? Any code snippets?

Comment: No , I have just gone through a whole lot of tutorials and texts trying to look for something that I can implement yo suit my need . I havent coded anything yet and this is my first time implementing Push Notification too.

Comment: I see. I also noticed that you have the [tag:phpmyadmin] in your post, I'm presuming it's the *hosted server*. Why not just make use of the Firebase database itself? And then use the real-time database capabilities of Firebase. But do note that using the Firebase database would keep an extra socket open (refer to Puf's [reply](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37760463/4625829) to my comment).

Comment: Alright , I can change that. Ill make it a firebase hosted server, I was planning to host it on 000webhost but firebase hosting seems more logical

Comment: Now that were on the subject, since you're using both Firebase and GCM, why not just go ahead and use [tag:firebase-cloud-messaging] (FCM)?

Comment: I don't know about this.  Can you please elaborate a bit about it and how it works ?

Comment: Read it's docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: Thank You So much . I'll give everything a read now

Answer (score 1):

You must send `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` to your server when user logs in and assign it to user in database.
Than you can send push notifications from server using POST request.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=SERVER_KEY_HERE

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "USER_TOKEN_HERE"
}
```

You can find your server key in Cloud Messaging Tab in your firebase project settings.

Links:

[Set Up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

[Downstream messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream)

Comment: Assign it to the user in which database.? The main server hosted database ?  That is make my firebase ID the unique key of the main database table and fetch results according to that ?

Comment: In main server hosted database. Firebase ID just another property of your user model in database. You just need to find user's push token by it's id when necessary.

Comment: Okay . Thank You . I'll give all this a try

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have all the Registration Ids of GCM. Now considering your requirement I suggest you to use [Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/). They have given all the things in order to send Push notification to your mobile.Admin can even easily post the data he want. If you do have a lot of registration Ids then simple export a CSV file from MySQL phpmyadmin and upload it on AWS SNS.

You just have to pay RS 2/- in order to have access to services later on it comes under PAYG.
Thank you.
I'm sure it'll help.

Comment: Alright ,I'll check it out . I am looking out for new things to try , I have no clue about these stuff anyways.

Comment: Yeah , AWS really very amazing. There are two fields 1.User data 2.Regids of GCM . You can upload your credential by creating new app on SNS.

Comment: Any tutorial or documentation that you can provide that can help me out here ?

Comment: [GCM using PHP MySql] (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: I tried using that tutorial  , but they methods are deprecated as it says on the post

Comment: Go to AWS SNS there is link to download the platform application like GCM ADM etc.